# Arduino: sending an integer array over UDP

Tags: c, arrays, arduino, udp

I'm new to Arduino and fairly new to programming.  I'm trying to send an array of integers over UDP to MaxMSP.  Using the .print method in the WiFiUDP library works for sending one integer per packet:

```
void loop() {

 Udp.beginPacket(hostIP, HOST_PORT);
 Udp.print("start");

 for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_SENSORS; i++) {   
   int adcValue = analogRead(i);
   Udp.print(adcValue);
 }

 Udp.endPacket();
 Udp.flush();
}
```

The problem is that this is quite slow.  I'm getting a refresh rate of about 10 ms for each sensor on the Max end, and I'm assuming that by writing all of the integers (only 4 at the moment) to a single buffer and sending it in its own packet, I'd be able to quadruple the speed.  I've tried this:

```
void loop() {

 byte sensorBuffer [NUMBER_OF_SENSORS * 2];

 for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_SENSORS; i++) {     
   int adcValue = analogRead(i);
   sensorBuffer[i*2] = highByte(adcValue);
   sensorBuffer[i*2+1] = lowByte(adcValue);
   }

 Udp.beginPacket(hostIP, HOST_PORT);
 Udp.write(sensorBuffer, NUMBER_OF_SENSORS * 2);
 Udp.endPacket();
 Udp.flush();
}
```

This produces garbage on the Max end.  I have a vague idea why this is the case - the array is formatted as 7-bit ASCII values? - but I haven't been able to figure out how to get it to work.  Any input is much appreciated.